# Is it possible to create an index concurrently in Postgres using GORM?

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

Postgress allows creating indexes with the `concurrently` option
(https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-createindex.html).

This allows building the index without locking the tables.
Is it possible to allow gorm to use this option?

On the other end, what is the default behavior of `AutoMigrate()` will it wait until the index is successfully built before returning?

Comment: Have you tried asking directly to the gorm project on GitHub?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I asked and they started working on it:
https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/issues/4423

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature has been implemented and now is possible to add the `CONCURRENTLY` option via the struct metadata:

```golang
// PostgreSQL option
type User struct {
  Name string `gorm:"index:,option:CONCURRENTLY"`
}
```

- Docs: https://gorm.io/docs/indexes.html
- Github Pull Request: https://github.com/go-gorm/postgres/pull/47